# Pass parameter to apex class method referenced in trigger through LWC

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-web-components, before-trigger, developer-console

I have a trigger where I'm calling a method from handler class and I'm passing the **trigger.New** to that method like this:

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        List<Lead> lstLead = Trigger.New;
        LeadHandler.assignLeadsToQueue(lstLead);        
    }
```

But Now I have a requirement where I want to pass another dynamic string value to that method in the apex class like this:

```
public static void assignLeadsToQueue(List<Lead> lstLead, String queueName){
List<Group> lstQueue = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' AND Name LIKE : queueName];

List<GroupMember> grpList = [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN : lstQueue];
     
List<AggregateResult> userIdWithLeadCountList = [SELECT OwnerId, Status, COUNT(Id) leadCount FROM Lead WHERE ((OwnerId IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN : lstQueue)) AND (Status = 'Open - Not Contacted' OR Status = 'Working - Contacted')) GROUP BY OwnerId, Status ORDER BY COUNT(Id)];

   **Another Logic with List<Lead> lstLead, List<GroupMember> grpList and List<AggregateResult> userIdWithLeadCountList**
}
```

The **String queueName** is coming from the LWC.

Now, I'm facing issue in passing the value because the trigger shown the error if I do not add String parameter to the method.
(We cannot pass the parameter directly to trigger via LWC)

How can I do that

Comment: If the trigger and the LWC are doing different things, you should have separate methods. If there's some common code, put that into a third, shared method called from the trigger and LWC specific methods.

Comment: Hi Phil W, I have made the changes can you pls check again

Comment: you can also use method overloading. You could define two method with same name but with different parameter

Comment: Hi Parag, the scenario is, I have apex class method where I'm passing trigger.New and in the same method I need to pass dynamic value through LWC

Comment: I stand by more comment; using the same method to do two different things is bad practice. Keep methods having focused roles and responsibilities. Split the common code into a separate method and call this from the two places its needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would just add the queue name to the trigger:

```
LeadHandler.assignLeadsToQueue(lstLead, 'Queue to assign to');
```

You can use literal parameters to pass in to a method.

Comment: Hi, the queue name is not static, it can change from the picklist value selected in LWC component where different queue names are present

Comment: @AdityaDeshmukh I guess your question is unclear, then. Why do you have this trigger at all? The purpose of a trigger is to do some logic in all contexts, but it sounds like you only want to do the assignment from the LWC? If that's the case, just write an AuraEnabled method to call so you can do the assignment there.